# jQuery - Sending "Select All" Check boxes with Multiple Forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, smarty

I have checked online for a solution to pass my values for the checkbox **`"select all"`**. I have multiple forms in a page. So I will need to separate passing the values based on specific forms.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".select-all").change(function () {
  $(this).siblings().prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
  });
})
```

HTML for form:**

```
<div class="col">
     <fieldset>
          <form action="{$link->getLink('controller')|escape:'htmlall':'utf-8'}" method="post"> 
            <p>
              {foreach from=$payment item=row}
              <input type="checkbox" name="payment[]" maxlength="50" value={$row.id_order}>
                <label> ID: <b>{$row.id_order}</b></label><br/>
                 {/foreach}
                <br/>
              <input id="submit" name="submitpayment" type="submit" value="PACK ITEMS" class="button" />
             </p>
         </form>
     </fieldset>
</div>
```

**`Error (Value is empty):`**

input type="checkbox" class="select-all" name="payment[]" value=""

SQL query to pass records:

```
public function displayOrdersbyID()
{
$query1 = new DbQuery();
$query1->select('o.id_order')
->from('orders','o')
->leftJoin('carrier','c','o.id_carrier=c.id_carrier')
->leftJoin('order_state_lang','s','o.current_state=s.id_order_state')
->where('c.name = ' . "'XXX'")
->where('s.name = ' . "'Payment accepted'");
$payment = Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->executeS($query1);
$this->context->smarty->assign( 'payment', $payment);
```

Controller:

```
    if (Tools::isSubmit('submitpayment')) { 
    $ids= Tools::getValue('payment');

    $query18 = new DbQuery();
    $query18->select('id_order_state')
    ->from('order_state_lang')
    ->where('name = ' . "'Processing in progress'");
    $updateinprogress = Db::getInstance()->getValue($query18);

    foreach ($ids as $updateids) {
            $objOrder = new Order($updateids);
            $history = new OrderHistory();
            $history->id_order = (int)$objOrder->id;
            $history->id_employee = $cookie->id_employee;
            $history->changeIdOrderState($updateinprogress, (int)($objOrder->id));
            $history->add(true);
            $history->save();
        }
    }
```

SELECT ALL checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="select-all" name="payment[]" value=
{$row.id_order}> 
<label> SELECT ALL</label>
```

I was using the above code to create a SELECT ALL checkbox for the form, placing it outside the loop. I understand it is wrong and value is not passing, where should I place the checkbox at?

Any guidance is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Would be good if you can add a Jsfiddle or codepen example.

Comment: I have updated the codes. I am retrieving the records from a php controller and assigned to a smarty template. Thus the codes as follow: {foreach from=$payment item=row}
              <input type="checkbox" name="payment[]" maxlength="50" value={$row.id_order}>
                <label> ID: <b>{$row.id_order}</b></label><br/>
                 {/foreach}. Just that I am facing problems with "select all" currently.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem in `select-all` value because there no initialization for `$row.id_order` in

```
<input type="checkbox" class="select-all" name="inprogress[]" value={$row.id_order}>
```

But if you assign the value of **`$row.id_order`** then might be not used in the following child like the `{foreach from=$payment item=row}` must use another variable identifier then **`row`**.

you working with a wrong practice you can't assign $row.order_id outside the loop.If there you want to use these element value in PHP then no need to do anything the `$_POST['payment']` for the second form and `$_POST['inprogress']` will return the value you want.
if no checkbox is selected then the result is returned blank.
and remember this will return an array type object.

Comment: Yes, precisely. I believe that is why for the first form, it is empty and I unable  to send the values over. It is returning an error due to this. Is there a way to overcome though?

Comment: Yes apparently  you have to change the row variable to another variable for inner element like `{foreach from=$payment item=row_i}` or something else for the same

Comment: Sorry if I do not get your solution but I cannot change {foreach from=$payment item=row} as it will not work anymore. Values are retrieved by {$row_i.id_order}

Comment: But why you can't change this ??

Comment: this only used as a variable for each item as i know that can be change as per your need

Comment: I have updated the codes. I am retrieving the records from a php controller and assigned to a smarty template. Thus the codes as follow: {foreach from=$payment item=row} <input type="checkbox" name="payment[]" maxlength="50" value={$row.id_order}> <label> ID: <b>{$row.id_order}</b></label><br/> {/foreach}. Just that I am facing problems with "select all" currently. So if i change .row, it will not display the id in the form.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160997/discussion-between-addy-and-enthu).

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
<input type="checkbox" class="select-all" name="inprogress[]" value={$row.id_order}>
```

lies outside the loop. Thus the value of `{$row.id_order}` will not be defined in your template. Check the DOM tree for compiled value.

And what is your final goal with the SELECT ALL button ? Is there any relation between the two forms?

Edit:

See the value of output variable. You can collect this value and pass it along with form submission.

```
<div class="col">
     <fieldset>
          <form> 
            <p>
              <input type="checkbox" class="select-all" name="payment[]" value="22">
                <label> SELECT ALL</label>
                <br/><br/>
              <input type="checkbox" name="payment[]" maxlength="50" value="a">
                <label> ID: <b>A</b></label><br/>
              <input type="checkbox" name="payment[]" maxlength="50" value="b">
                <label> ID: <b>B</b></label><br/>
              <input id="submit" name="submitinprogress" type="submit" value="PACK ITEMS" class="button" />
             </p>
         </form>
     </fieldset>
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".select-all").change(function () {
        $(this).siblings().prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
        let inputs = $(this).siblings("input[type=checkbox]");
        let output = [];
        for(let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
            output.push(inputs[i].value);
        };
        console.log(output);    // ["a", "b"]
    });
});
```

Comment: If I were to put inside the loop, it will create multiple SELECT ALL checkboxes. I will need one for each form though. SELECT ALL will take in all the records and submit into controller to process. There is no relation between the two forms.

Comment: So first of all, remove the {$row.id_order} from SELECT ALL checkbox. Secondly, I suppose for submitting the values of these boxes, you are either using an array or object data type.

Comment: Alright, I have been doing it wrong all the while. How do I create a select box to pass the values over?

Comment: Hello @rach8garg, I will need to use               {foreach from=$payment item=row}
              <input type="checkbox" name="payment[]" maxlength="50" value={$row.id_order}>
                <label> ID: <b>{$row.id_order}</b></label><br/>
                 {/foreach} to display the list. As such, how can I incorporate SELECT ALL?

Comment: Perhaps you should run my code once and dig deeper into detail.